# How can I obtain org.hibernate.Query from javax.persistence.EntityManager?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

How can I obtain **org.hibernate.Query** from **javax.persistence.EntityManager** object? *(hibernate 4.0.1)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First obtain the `org.hibernate.Session`:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

Then use the `session` to create the query as usual:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Stock where stockCode = :code ");
```

Comment: And as to why anyone would do that when they have the EntityManager in the first place is unclear ...

Comment: I had to use it once because JPA's api for what I wanted to achieve was waaay too complex. On the other hand Hibernate's was quite simple.